Issues while installing .NET Framework 4.5.2
My project require to install 4.5.2 framework.
I recently installed VS2022 on my system. When I try to open project it ask below dialog.

I has to select "Download .NET Framework 4.5.2 targeting pack(Opens in browser)" option. It open page in browser. I downloaded 4.5.2 runtime and trying to install it. while installing it shows below error.

Problem is, while installing it is saying 4.5.2 version is already installed, but while opening project it is asking to install.
I refer few articles which suggest to see registry file, which is below.

Thanks in advance.

"My project require to install 4.5.2 framework" - No. it really doesn't.. You can't (and shouldn't even attempt) to install old versions of .NET Framework 4 on Windows 11. .NET 4.8 is compatible with 4.5.2. Your job should really be to update that project to this decade.

You said it yourself; "I downloaded 4.5.2 runtime and trying to install it." The runtime and the targeting pack isn't the same thing.

Why would you use an out of date unsupported version of .NET Framework?

I just upgraded my solution to 4.8. and won't commit my project file. able to load. thank you
